# Setting up Application Insights for an App Service container deployment

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, fastapi

I was trying to figure out how to enable Application Insights for a containerized REST API that I’ve hosted on app service (it’s a custom FastAPI docker container). I've already created the app insights resource and linked it to the app service, but the data doesn't show up on the application insights page.

I went through several pages of documentation and it didn’t have anything specifically for container deployments on app service. I found [this page in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python) that suggested adding some telemetry code for python, but it didn't work for me.

Here's a minimal replication of the main file where I tried adding the telemetry code:

```
from typing import Dict, List
from file import main_function

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure import metrics_exporter
from opencensus.stats import stats as stats_module
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

stats = stats_module.stats
view_manager = stats.view_manager
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
conn_string = 'InstrumentationKey=<instrumentation key here>'
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(connection_string=conn_string))

app = FastAPI()

exporter = metrics_exporter.new_metrics_exporter(enable_standard_metrics=True, connection_string=conn_string)
view_manager.register_exporter(exporter)

class Request(BaseModel):
    text: str


class Response(BaseModel):
    response: Dict[str, List[Dict[str, str]]]


@app.get('/')
async def health_check():
    return {'status': 'ok'}


@app.post("/endpoint", response_model=Response)
async def predict(request: Request):
    try:
        response = main_function(request.text)
        return Response(response=response)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Error: {e}")
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you use OpenTelemetry, you can have to look for the Traces in the Logs-blad of application insights. This way we could find them, however we use FastAPI in a non-containerised AppService.

Comment: Traces are okay, but I need the performance metrics as well, which are not visible on the app insights page

Comment: Metrics are not done automatically AFAIK, but you should aggregate and send the metrics yourself. In Azure Functions this is done by the service itself. You might consider using a background task to collect this over a period of time and then send info every 5 minutes or so (note that metrics is limited in the amount of datapoints per time).

Comment: See the example on sending metrics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#count-aggregation-example